# Does ORM ODB for C++ Object Persistence Create/Re-Create DB

Tags: c++, orm, persistence, odb-orm

I am fairly new to this library, and ORM in general. I know tools like EntityFramework can generate a database from your objects, and can generate code from a database. Can ODB for C++ do anything similar? If not, are there libraries that can do such, for C++?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, ODB can generate database schema (i.e., DDL statements) for your C++ object model. You can have it either as a separate .sql file or embed it into the C++ code and create the schema programmatically from your application.

See the --generate-schema and --schema-format options in the [ODB Compiler Manual](http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/odb/doc/odb.xhtml).

Comment: That's awesome, but what happens when my classes change in the future and a user has a database with the old data in it? I've asked that question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13632093/handling-class-changes-when-using-orm-such-as-odb